# How to implement timer in phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am trying to add a timer in my phonegap application. Is there any way to implement it or any plugin is available? Please help me how to implement it.

Comment: What kind of timer? What should it do? Phonegap uses javascript so any javascript timer should suffice depending on your exact requirements.

Comment: i found a way to implement it but how to start a timer when a page has finished loading in jquery mobile

Comment: See: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageload/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get source code as well as demo for timer from [this link](http://jchavannes.com/jquery-timer/demo)

Use the below code to implement the timer

```
var count = 0;
var timer = $.timer(function() {
    $('#counter').html(++count);
});
timer.set({ time : 1000, autostart : true });
```

There are many other options also which you can explore.
For example

```
var Example1 = new (function() {

    // Stopwatch element on the page
    var $stopwatch;

    // Timer speed in milliseconds
    var incrementTime = 70;

    // Current timer position in milliseconds
    var currentTime = 0;

    // Start the timer
    $(function() {
        $stopwatch = $('#stopwatch');
        Example1.Timer = $.timer(updateTimer, incrementTime, true);  
    });

    // Output time and increment
    function updateTimer() {
        var timeString = formatTime(currentTime);
        $stopwatch.html(timeString);
        currentTime += incrementTime;
    }

    // Reset timer
    this.resetStopwatch = function() {
        currentTime = 0;
        Example1.Timer.stop().once();
    };

});
```

Hope this helps.!

Answer (score 0):

You should try a plugin to enable continuous timer in background.
For me, I am currently using a plugin called: ["cordova-background-timer"](https://github.com/dukhanov/cordova-background-timer), but you have to be aware for the next:

1. This is an android only plugin and not working on ios.
2. The plugin runs in background, and you can choose to "reopen" your app automatically in case it was terminated.
   In this case, you should run the timer again when the app is on, and to do that, you have to set 10 seconds JS timer (by setTimeout function) to restart the timer because the app needs some time to start the plugin.
3. In my case, And for unknown reason for me, the timer runs every 5 minutes although I defined it with 60 seconds.

That's it, hope this is useful for somebody.